# Using AlarmManager to set multiple alarms, everything executes fine but no alarm

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to set a bunch of alarms based on a list of minutes entered by the user.  If they hit the start clock button at 4:00pm and had 5 min, 10 min and 15 min alarms set then I need alarms set for 4:05, 4:10 and 4:15.  The code I have seeeems right and the Toast sends me a "Set alarm" message for each item I have in the list, but no alarms are going off on my phone:

```
setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] spAlarms = allAlarms.split(";");
                for(int i = 0; i < spAlarms.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        if(!spAlarms.equals("")) {
                            int time = Integer.valueOf(spAlarms[i]);
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, time);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Hop_Timer.this, Alarm_Receiver.class);
                            intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Time for your " + spAlarms[i] + " min addition!");
                            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Hop_Timer.this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do this in OnClickListener, but a better solution is to do this in `OnResume()`

and Ekta Parikh is right that you must use `cal.set(Calender.MINUTE, time);` do be able to set the alarm

Answer (score -1):

Use cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time); instead of add method.